# How to loop a google spreadsheet column values and set result in column B?

Tags: loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a list of urls in column A and i want to loop this column A and set the  status code for each url to column B. I tried this code but i keep getting **Range not found** in script editor window? i know i have to add the value of row to name of column B but i keep getting this error.could any one tell me how to fix this error .Thanks in advance.

```
function getStatus() {

    var queryString = Math.random();

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"),
      urls = sheet.getRange("A2:A").getValues(),

      row, len


  for (row = 0, len = urls.length; row < len; row++) {
    if (urls[row] != '') {

        var cellFunction1 = '=HTTPResponse("' + urls[row] + '?' + queryString + '")';
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('"B"+row+').setValue(cellFunction1);

     } 
  }

  }

function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
 var response_code ;
try {
 response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
 }
catch( error ) {
 response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] ;
 }
finally {
 return response_code ;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are probably better (and more elegant) ways to do it, but at least this seems to work:

```
 function getStatus() {    

  var queryString = Math.random();    

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn(); 
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, lastRow -1, lastColumn);
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var row = 0;
  var len = data.length;


  for (row; row < len; row++) {
    if (data[row] != '') {    

        var cellFunction1 = '=HTTPResponse("' + data[row][0] + '?' + queryString + '")';
        // change the following line, last number for another column
        var cell = sheet.getRange(row+2, 2);
        cell.setValue(cellFunction1);

     } 
  }    

  }    

function HTTPResponse( uri )
{
 var response_code ;
try {
 response_code = UrlFetchApp .fetch( uri ) .getResponseCode() .toString() ;
 }
catch( error ) {
 response_code = error .toString() .match( / returned code (\d\d\d)\./ )[1] ;
 }
finally {
 return response_code ;
 }
}
```

Maybe you can go from here and improve it.
[screenshot spreadsheet columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOT0R.png)

Comment: Thanks it worked. could you explain to my which part we specify the start of column index that we want to start the status data to?For example if i want to paste the result to column C instead of B  which part should i change?

Comment: I added a comment in the code, you have to change the line "var cell = sheet.getRange(row+2, 2);". The last number is the column, e.g. change it to "3" for column "C". This is the part that looks a bit hacky to myself, getting the range for a second time inside the loop, there is room for improvement, I think.

Comment: this will not work because a custom function called from a cell will cache forever the result after the first call (per url)

Comment: But a trigger set every couple of minutes should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: no it wont. once you verify it wont work, uncheck the answer and i can provide an answer

Comment: I'm afraid I can't uncheck, I answered. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Now I checked with a trigger, used one of my sites, shut down the server and got after the trigger kicked in and the function ran again an "ERROR" in the sheet. For a not existing page I got a "404".