# Loop through column with function, put result in column next to it in Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I use an API to retrieve data with an UUID. I call the API with a script and the UrlFetchApp, works like a charm.

Now I want to put the name (result) in the column right next to the UUID column. The UUID column is B (B8:B) and I want the name for that UUID in column C. The function needs to be run every 24 hours, so I want to use a trigger for that.

For retrieving the name via the API, I use the following code:

```
function getNameFromUUID(uuid){
  if(uuid != ""){
    var api_uuid = uuid.replace(/-/g,'');
    var url = "API-URL/" + api_uuid;
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
    if(response.getContentText() != ""){
      var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).reverse();
      return json[0].name.toString();
    }else{
      return "Error";
    }
  }else{
    return "";
  }
}
```

**So the question:** How can I mass-call the function with data from B8:B and put the output in C8:C using a script function so I can call that function with a time-based trigger?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: The question is how i can mass-call a function with input column B8:B and put the output in C8:C.

Comment: @Joep Welcome. There's an excellent topic in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) called [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and the very first item is **search and research**. Possibly you might have found [How to loop a google spreadsheet column values and set result in column B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060573/) which seems to be exactly the same thing you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to loop a google spreadsheet column values and set result in column B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060573/how-to-loop-a-google-spreadsheet-column-values-and-set-result-in-column-b)