# Google Script For Loop Issues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So this question seems to be beaten to death on the boards, but with all my reading and googling, I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm trying to adapt the code from this link
[How to loop a google spreadsheet column values and set result in column B?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060573/how-to-loop-a-google-spreadsheet-column-values-and-set-result-in-column-b)

Below is what I've adapted it to

```
function EquationIterationTest(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = s.getSheetByName('Heath, OH')
  var drng = sht.getDataRange();
  var rng = sht.getRange(13, 2, 111, 1)
  //.getRange(13, 2, drng.getLastRow()-1, drng.getLastColumn())
  var rngA = rng.getValues();//Array of input values

  Logger.log(rngA);

  for(var i = 0; i < rngA.length; i++) {
    if(rngA[i][0] === 'subtotal'){
    rng.offset(0,3).setFormula('=iferror(sum(filter(Invoices!$E:$E,Invoices!$F:$F=$B14,Invoices!$A:$A=$C$2)))');
    }
   else{
     rng.offset(0,3).setValue('Dumb');
   }
   }
 }
```

When I run this, rngA does get the first column of values (which in this instance starts at B13) however, it will not input the formula in the third column of values. Instead it moves right through the first if statement and executes the else statement. The only thing I can think is there's something wrong either with my if statement or my array.

I tried setting `if(rngA[i][0] === 'subtotal')` to `if(rngA[i][1] === 'subtotal')`, but that still returned "dumb" on every line.

Any help would be appreciated so I can stop being "dumb"!

Here's the link to my sheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cDkwWThXDTssH89gJX7W1zKzsW86oLXO-FPfAIJvc-g/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks

Comment: Log some information in order to see what's happening. Put log statements Inside your "for" loop, at the top, before the "if" test:  `Logger.log(rngA[i][0]);Logger.log(rngA[i][0] === 'subtotal');`

Comment: Link a copy of your sheet too, **removing sensitive data**

Comment: So that got me a little closer. now I have number popping up, but the equation is written in every field, not just the subtotal fields.

Comment: Just added a copy of the sheet with the sensitive data removed.

Comment: The sheet is not public

Comment: My bad. fixed it.

Comment: Should it be rngA[i][0] === 'Subtotal'? I see "Subtotal" in the spreadsheet not "subtotal"

Comment: unfortunately capitalizing 'subtotal' does not change the way the loop is functioning. It still places the equation in all cells in the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in your if condition, although if you use three equal signs you are making a strict comparison, so subtotal in your case should start with capital letter.

That said, your problem is happening when you assign a value or formula to `rng.offset(0,3)`, because the result of that expression is a range with the same size as `rng` but offset 3 columns to the right. You can verify this by using: `Logger.log(rng.offset(0,3).getA1Notation());`, thus whenever you assign a value or formula there you are assigning it to the whole offset rng. Not what you want right?

You should use `offset()` from a single cell in your case, not a whole range.

Your function could be simplified to something like the following:

```js
function EquationIterationTest(){
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sht = s.getSheetByName('Heath, OH')
  var rng = sht.getRange(13, 2, 111, 1)

  for(var i = 1; i <= rng.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var cell = rng.getCell(i,1);
    if(cell.getValue() === 'Subtotal'){
      cell.offset(0,3).setFormula(
        '=iferror(sum(filter(Invoices!$E:$E,Invoices!$F:$F=$B14,Invoices!$A:$A=$C$2)))'
      );
    }
    else{
      cell.offset(0,3).setValue('Dummy');
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked, thank you! Is there any way to make it run faster?

Answer (score 0):

So I want to make sure I put this here because while the answer above was previously correct, I figured out a much faster way to do it using arrays. This function checks against the data range for a value (in this case "Subtotal") and then appends the equation to rows that that do not contain that value. It is easy to make it compare against the value though by changing the operator from != to ==.

```
    function NewIterationTest(){
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var data = activeSheet.getRange(13, 2, 112, 1).getValues();

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){

        var rowData = data[i];
        var checkData = data;
        var row = checkData[i];
        var colB = row[0]; 

        if(colB != 'Subtotal'{

          activeSheet.getRange(13 + i, 5).setFormula('=iferror(sum(filter(Invoices!$E:$E,Invoices!$F:$F=$B14,Invoices!$A:$A=$C$2)))');
        }

      }
    }
```

However, if anyone could tell me how to also eliminate compare against whether or not a the text is bold, that would be helpful. Not sure it can be done though since it's pulling against the array.